# Installing raster resampling module in QGIS

Tags: qgis, raster, qgis-plugins, installation

On the website of Sourcepole, I have recently come across the case of resampling images in Quantum GIS. Because I am rather a beginner in GIS software I would like to ask you for information about how I can enable/install the resampling option (as shown [here](http://sourcepole.ch/raster-resampling-in-qgis)) on QuantumGIS 1.8., (perhaps it is obvious, but not for me).

Answer (score 3):

Raster resampling is available by default in the current development version (which is titled QGIS 1.9) and will be available in QGIS 2.0 which should be release soon. As far as I know, there is no way to get it work in 1.8.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the tool inside the SAGA toolbox. Open the toolbox and search "Resampling". It has both scale up and down algorithms.